# How to dynamically handle a multitude of filters with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filter, react-redux

I am currently working on an online store that filters products based on certain criteria such as size, stock, gender, etc.

While I have been able to make it work to a certain extent. My program currently filters by size, gender, sorts by price etc. However, I cannot get it to filter by brand. For some reason once I click on the brand, I am able to filter the function once, however, once I click on another brand the filter for that particular brand does not run.

Here is the link to the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-7mp0t

I am currently stuck with filtering by brand and I have tried to compared my filtered result to the state of the item clicked, by checking if the brand is included in the item and by using localeCompare().

Here is the link to the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-7mp0t

```
createCheckboxes = () => available_sizes.map(this.createCheckbox);

  handleFormSubmit = event => {
    //4) this button updates the filters on the sizes, which I think I need to fix to update the brands, the price and the gender
    event.preventDefault();
    //5) right here I am storing the selected checkboxes which is what I was doing before by pushing the checkboxes
    const selectedSizes = [...this.selectedCheckboxes];

    const shallowCopy = [...this.state.filteredProducts];
    let filteredProducts = shallowCopy.filter(product =>
      selectedSizes.every(size =>
        product.stock.some(s => s.stock > 0 && s.size === size)
      )
    );


    let filteredGender = filteredProducts.filter(product => {
      return product.gender.some((item, idx, arr) => {
        return item[this.selectedGender] === false ? null : product;
      });
    });


    //***this is the function that is not currently running***//
    let filteredData = filteredGender.filter(product => {
      //console.log(product.brand.includes(this.state.activeBrand))
      //console.log(product.brand = this.state.brand)

      return product.brand.includes(this.state.activeBrand)
    });

    let sortedPrice = filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
      return this.state.sortBy === "min"
        ? a.price - b.price
        : b.price - a.price;
    });


    this.setState({
      filteredProducts: sortedPrice
    });

  };
```

I am expecting to be able to filter by brand wit this function, once an item is clicked.

Here is the link to the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-7mp0t

Comment: unless I am mistaken, at line 549, you assign ```console.log(product.brand = this.state.brand)``` which is doubly wrong: you silently assign stuff (you ought to use a comma to log), and ```this.state.brand``` is void (hence all your products are filtered out thereafter). By actually removing the console.log I seem able to filter by brand

Comment: Awesome dude, I was just using that for debugging purposes but I was not aware of the weird bug it was causing. I appreciate it man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your application:

1) the first one is reported by @user753642 in comment to your question, remove this line from `index.js`, because it sets your `brand` of all products to `""`:

```js
console.log(product.brand = this.state.brand)
```

2) you are filtering `filteredProducts` and no the all `products`. While after first filtering on brand the `filterdProducts` does not have any item of other brands, it returns an empty collection after filtering on another brand. Change line in `handleFormSubmit` in `index.js`, from:

```js
const shallowCopy = [...this.state.filteredProducts];
```

to:

```js
const shallowCopy = [...this.state.products];
```

Comment: That absolutely solved the issue. Thanks a lot boss!